# No Orchard.sln in download zip

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am reading "Orchard CMS Up and Running".

It says to start developing, download the zip file from the main orchard website (OrchardProject.net) - and load Orchard.sln. This file does not exist in the download zip?!

This appears to be the only book on the subject - how can I load the files as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded the runtime distribution. You should get a source code drop instead. That will contain orchard.sln under /src.

Comment: Thanks - not sure if I'm being stupid or that isn't obvious enough?! Wouldn't do any harm to emphasize this somewhere on Codeplex?

Comment: It's specified in the release notes, which are linked to from the CodePlex download page: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-6-Release-Notes#Whatfiletodownload?

Comment: I guess I missed it - maybe make it more prominent?